# How to show a specific object in object array (Angular 5, TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a data provider in Angular 5.

```
export class DataProvider {
  location: any;

  private locations: any[] = [
    {
      "name": "restaurant",
      "location": "downtown",
      "category": "restaurant",
      "id": "1"
    },

    {
      "name": "law firm",
      "location": "center city",
      "category": "office",
      "id": "2"
    },

    {
      "name": "public library",
      "location": "suburb",
      "category": "library",
      "id": "3"
    } ]
```

and here's my HTML file.

```
<div *ngFor="let location of locations">
   <h1></h1>
    <h2></h2>
</div>
```

In this scenario, how can I load a specific object (item) in data array with certain attributes?
For instance, If I want to load an object with `"category" :"restaurant"`, what should I do on my HTML file? so the two others should not show up. I just want to load one out of three by using this specific attribute.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the attribute. You can use the following example

```
<div *ngFor="let location of locations">
   <h1>{{location.name}}</h1>
    <h2>{{location.category}}</h2>
</div>
```

#### EDIT

To filter depending on a category:

```
locationsFiltered = this.locations.filter(location =>location.category=="restaurant");
```

Now to make this example practical I will create a method to do it

```
filter(category : string) : any[] {
   return this.locations.filter(location =>location.category==category);
}
```

then in html

```
<div *ngFor="let location of locationsFiltered">
   <h1>{{location.name}}</h1>
    <h2>{{location.category}}</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I know how to do that. But my question is, If I want to load an object with "category":"restaurant" only, what should I do? the two others should not show up.

Comment: I want to be able to load one out of three.. by calling up a specific attributes for that object. How can I do that? Thanks I will wait for your edit.

Comment: Thanks for your edit! I really appreciate your help. I will try this now.

Comment: I just gave you the tools. I'll let use them. I advise to use a select list https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_select&stacked=h

Comment: For the final html, don't you need {{location.name}} and {{location.category}} between the header tags (as in your first html snippet)?  (If so just edit and I'll delete my comment.)